# How to debug powershell scripts on a NAS in a remote session in VS Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I want to debug scripts on a NAS while they're running on a remote machine in VS Code. I'm actually able to do this but I have to open the script twice: I have all the scripts already open in VS Code, but debug works only If I reopen the file with `PSedit <filename>` executed in the remote session so that it opens another editor view with italic  title where I can debug the code with breakpoints and inspect variables while the script is running on the remote PC.
Is there a way to set breakpoints in the already open scripts on VS Code (remember they aro on a NAS) without opening editors for the same scripts from the point of view of the remote machine?

What I expect is when I open VS Code it opens automatically all of my scripts I'm working on; then I would launch and debug directly on a remote PC.
I suppose that the answer is in launch.json but I tried several configuration and none of them works. Just "PowerShell Launch Current File" works, but it is uncomfortable to use.

Please explain as simple as you can.
Every help will be appretiated!